# IntellijJ: Resizing Window with keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to use the keyboard shortcut  `Shift+Command+[Left|Right|Up|Down]` to resize windows in intelliJ. But it doesn't work. Weirdly, in `Window->Active Tool Window -> Resize` I do see the option to apply the same options `Stretch To [Left|Right|Up|Down]` along with the corresponding shortcut key combination and that usually works for all windows except the editor window in which all the four options are shadowed even when the editor windows isn't stretched to it's full extent. Anyone has any idea on what is going on?  I can do the resizing using the mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because these shortcuts only work in **tool windows** and the **editor** is not a tool window. From [Tool Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html):

> Attached to the bottom and sides of the workspace are IntelliJ IDEA tool windows.
>   [...]
>
> [image: tool windows attached to editor]

Within the editor, the shortcuts have different meaning:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> – Move caret to line start with selection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> – Move caret to line end with selection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> – Move statment up
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> – Move statment down

The editor doesn't have a specific size, it uses the available space. To make it larger or smaller, you have to resize the attached tool windows.

Comment: You can now maximize the size of the window, especially if you have multiple windows, like buffers in vim, with the `MaximizeEditorInSplit` IdeaVim command, or pressing Shift + Shift then Maximize Editor. You can also set this to happen with a double-click on the tab with Shift + Shift Perform Maximize Editor ... in Advanced Preferences.